# Ubuntu 18.04.1 XRDP startup failure

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I saw a number of posts SIMILAR to this one but not with the identical error and I'm finding those answers are just having me chase down blind alleys.  XRDP did once work on this machine... prior to upgrading to 18.04.1.  I do not think "a newer version" of xrdp is the solution as this appears to have the latest build.  Attempting to start xrdp fails with this bit of error:

```
Job for xrdp.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status xrdp.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@play:/home/richard# systemctl status xrdp.service
? xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-21 18:20:28 EDT; 10s ag
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 5542 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/F
  Process: 5534 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, st

Aug 21 18:20:28 play systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Aug 21 18:20:28 play systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exi
Aug 21 18:20:28 play systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 21 18:20:28 play systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
```

The journalctl command... the log is so lengthy as to be nearly useless.  I've no idea where its finding references to the users it seems to has listed there... the bottom line error seems to be an authentication failure which... is weird to me since... hey this is a process running on the server BY the server... what exactly would be logging into WHAT at this point... just to start that service.  But aside my own ignorance on that, I don't know where to add/change said users... looking into things like the PAM authentication list I see exactly none of the users being mentioned in the journal here so... changing anything there would not likely make any difference.

```
Aug 21 18:43:35 play sshd[6750]: Received disconnect from 116.31.116.34 port 51191:11:  [preauth]
Aug 21 18:43:35 play sshd[6750]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 116.31.116.34 port 51191 [preauth]
Aug 21 18:43:35 play sshd[6750]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=116.31.116.34  user=root
Aug 21 18:43:35 play sshd[6752]: Received disconnect from 116.31.116.34 port 46881:11:  [preauth]
Aug 21 18:43:35 play sshd[6752]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 116.31.116.34 port 46881 [preauth]
Aug 21 18:43:35 play sshd[6752]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=116.31.116.34  user=root
Aug 21 18:44:00 play sshd[6768]: rexec line 16: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
Aug 21 18:44:00 play sshd[6768]: rexec line 19: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Aug 21 18:44:00 play sshd[6768]: rexec line 20: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Aug 21 18:44:00 play sshd[6768]: rexec line 31: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Aug 21 18:44:00 play sshd[6768]: rexec line 38: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Aug 21 18:44:08 play sshd[6772]: rexec line 16: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
Aug 21 18:44:08 play sshd[6772]: rexec line 19: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Aug 21 18:44:08 play sshd[6772]: rexec line 20: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Aug 21 18:44:08 play sshd[6772]: rexec line 31: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Aug 21 18:44:08 play sshd[6772]: rexec line 38: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Aug 21 18:44:10 play sshd[6772]: reprocess config line 31: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Aug 21 18:44:10 play sshd[6772]: reprocess config line 38: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Aug 21 18:44:10 play sshd[6772]: Invalid user luser from 203.198.158.147 port 59930
Aug 21 18:44:10 play sshd[6772]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Aug 21 18:44:10 play sshd[6772]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=203.198.158.147
Aug 21 18:44:12 play sshd[6772]: Failed password for invalid user luser from 203.198.158.147 port 59930 ssh2
Aug 21 18:44:12 play sshd[6772]: Connection closed by invalid user luser 203.198.158.147 port 59930 [preauth]
```

Anyway during update it was mentioned several files that were possibly newer and could be replaced by newer versions... except that the prior ones were modified by some script (or me) since their install so the default action was to keep the previous one.  I'm guessing that replacing one of those with a newer one might remedy this issue, but I have no idea where to start on finding what that is.  Anyway if anyone came across THIS issue or one similar that they can guide me towards a correction direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The host said that they: "purged xrdp and reinstalled it".  After having done so xrdp works fine.